# Pass Metatype as function argument

Tags: swift, struct, metatype

In Swift I can do the following:

```
struct Employee{
    var name:String
    var age:Int
}

// Metatype
let currentType = Employee.self
// concrete instance
let instanceFromType = currentType.init(name: "Jessie", age: 54)

print(instanceFromType) // prints Employee(name: "Jessie", age: 54)
```

`currentType` is a `Metatype`: this means I could pass another struct name (eg. Person, etc.) and `instanceFromType` would contain a struct of another type.

But, suppose I want to pass `currentType` as a function argument and then, inside the body of the function, create `instanceFromType`: how would I do?

I tried this one:

```
func f(m:Any.Type){

  let instanceFromType = m.init(name: "Jessie", age: 54)
  print(instanceFromType)
}

f(m:currentType)
```

but I get:

> 'init' is a member of the type; use 'type(of: ...)' to initialize a new object of the same dynamic type

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

[UPDATE]

I forgot to mention that I found this one is working, but I really can't understand why:

```
protocol Proto {
    init(name:String,age:Int)
}

struct Employee:Proto{
    var name:String
    var age:Int
    init(name:String,age:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

let currentType = Employee.self

func f(m:Proto.Type){

    let instanceFromType = m.init(name: "Jessie", age: 54)
    print(instanceFromType)

}

f(m:currentType)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call `m.init(name: "Jessie", age: 54)` for an *arbitrary*
type `m`, because the type does not necessarily have such an
initializer.

What you can do is to define a *protocol* for a type which can
be initialized from those arguments, and restrict the argument
of `f` accordingly:

```
protocol InitializableFromNameAndAge {
    init(name: String, age: Int)
}

func f(type: InitializableFromNameAndAge.Type) {
    let instance = type.init(name: "Jessie", age: 34)
    print(instance)
}
```

Then declare protocol conformance for your types

```
struct Employee: InitializableFromNameAndAge {
    var name:String
    var age:Int
}
```

and then

```
let currentType = Employee.self
f(type: currentType)
```

works as expected.

Comment: I updated the question just to mention that, even if I could not understand why it worked (so, thanks!)

Comment: @3000: What do you not understand? Inside the function, the compiler *knows* that the given type has a `init(name: String, age: Int)` method. That what makes it different from your original approach.

Comment: And I was thanking you for that, I could not understand why the compiler was complaining and the error it returned was a little misleading for me (type:of, etc). You pointed me in the right direction